# Swift LocalAuthentication issue with faceID resetting my state vars. Stopped working with iOS 17

Tags: ios, swiftui, face-id, localauthentication

I'm trying to change a state bool var with faceID.

My Test Code.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import LocalAuthentication

struct PasswordEditTest: View {
    
    @State private var showPassword: Bool = false
  
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Section(header: Text("Password:").foregroundColor(Color.theme.red)
            ) {
                
                if  showPassword {
                    Text("UNLOCKED")
                }
                else {
                    Text("LOCKED")
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
             
             Image(systemName: showPassword ? "lock.open" : "lock")
                 .resizable()
                 .scaledToFill()
                 .frame(width: showPassword ? 30 : 30, height: showPassword ? 39 : 39)
                 .padding()
                 .onTapGesture {
                     
                     let context = LAContext()
                     var error: NSError?
                    
                     if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
                         let reason = "We need to unlock your password"
                         
                         context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, authenticationError in
                                 if success {
                                     
                                     print("SUCCESS")
                                     showPassword=true
                                    
                                 } else {
                                     
                                     print("FAIL")
                                     
                                     showPassword=false
                                    
                                 }
                             
                         }
                     } else {
                        //NO FACEID/Biometrics
                         
                     }
                     
                     
                 }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

If I change the showPassword to TRUE on the tap gesture, once the faceid success fires it will change the var back to false, So strange. It was working fine on iOS16

```swift
.onTapGesture {
                     showPassword=true //ADD THIS

                     let context = LAContext()
                     var error: NSError?
                    
                     if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
                         let reason = "We need to unlock your password"
                         
                         context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, authenticationError in
                                 if success {
                                     
                                  // the showPassword will change back to false. 

                                     print("SUCCESS")
                                     showPassword=true.  // This will not change it to true Crazy!
                                    
                                 } else {
                                     
                                     print("FAIL")
                                     
                                     showPassword=false
                                    
                                 }
                             
                         }
                     } else {
                        //NO FACEID/Biometrics
                         
                     }
```

Comment: Your code works for me as-is on iOS 17.2.1.  I do note that the documentation for [`evaluatePolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514176-evaluatepolicy) states that the closure is executed in an *unspecified threading context* so you should dispatch your state update onto the main queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to the `async/await` version, it will ensure that the result is received in the `MainActor`

```
import SwiftUI
import LocalAuthentication

struct PasswordResetTest: View {
    @State private var showPassword: Bool = false
    @State private var isEvaluatingPolicy: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Section(header: Text("Password:").foregroundColor(Color.red)
            ) {
                
                if  showPassword {
                    Text("UNLOCKED")
                }
                else {
                    Text("LOCKED")
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: showPassword ? "lock.open" : "lock")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: showPassword ? 30 : 30, height: showPassword ? 39 : 39)
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    //Start evaluating policy
                    isEvaluatingPolicy.toggle()
                }
                .task(id: isEvaluatingPolicy) {
                    guard isEvaluatingPolicy else {return}
                    let context = LAContext()
                    let policy: LAPolicy = .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                    do {
                        try context
                            .canEvaluatePolicy(policy)
                        showPassword = try await context
                            .evaluatePolicy(policy, localizedReason: "We need to unlock your password")
                        print("Was successful = \(showPassword.description)")
                    } catch {
                        print(error) //Should display error to user.
                    }
                    isEvaluatingPolicy = false //Done evaluating policy
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The referenced `canEvaluatePolicy` is a simple conversion of the existing methodology.

```
extension LAContext {
    /// Assesses whether authentication can proceed for a given policy.
    /// - Parameter policy: The policy to evaluate. For possible values,
    func canEvaluatePolicy(_ policy: LAPolicy) throws {
        var error: NSError?
        if self
            .canEvaluatePolicy(policy, error: &error) {
            //Done
        } else if let error {
            throw error
        } else {
            throw LocalError.cannotBeEvaluated(policy)
        }
    }
    
    private enum LocalError: LocalizedError {
        case cannotBeEvaluated(LAPolicy)
        var errorDescription: String?{
            switch self {
            case .cannotBeEvaluated(let lAPolicy):
                return "Policy cannot be evaluated."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but it still fails.  When the .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics is processed it will reset the showPassword back to the default value. I don't get it.  My target ios is 17.1. (for test) If I set showPassword=true and then process .canEvaluatePolicy(policy) it will instantly change the showPassword=false. Before I match the faceID. So strange!

Comment: @neogaz there is something else going on then that isn’t depicted in your sample. Something is changing the identity of the view.

Comment: You are correct. I went one level up in my tabview and it works, so odd ios 17 update killed something. It's been working great!  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @neogaz glad to help. Do you mind clicking on the green checkmark to accept the answer?